# How to get flake8 in $PATH

Tags: python, windows, atom-editor, flake8

Windows 7 with Atom IDE. 
Stick with me here, I'm new to using command line and atom.
flake8 error while running python in atom. 
terminal say file location for flake8 is: /c/Users/Parker/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Scripts/flake8

How do I get flake8 in my path for atom? I tried download the virtualenv and then abandoned that when I hit sudo:command not found. Figured there must be an easier way.

How do I do this? Been trying different methods for days and have exhausted the search function.

Comment: You do have flake8 installed somewhere? You can change the path to it in your settings. If not installed, start with that :) https://atom.io/packages/linter-flake8

Comment: I installed via pip. How do I change path to it?

Comment: You know the path of the flake8, so follow link I provided. Assuming you use linter-flake8. 
> Atom -> Preferences -> Packages -> linter-flake8.

Comment: I tried entering /c/Users/Parker/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Scripts/flake8 into 'executable path' in settings and that didn't fix it
edit: otherwise I'm familiar with the link you provided, That's the one I started with.

Comment: I've also tried /usr/bin/flake8. when I ls /usr/bin I don't see flake8, although it's been installed

Comment: That's the path for linux. perhaps these question can help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45707756/linter-flake8-and-atom-windows-10-path-to-cmd-exe

Comment: I've run that tutorial through as well. So my errors in atom look like the ones at the bottom of this page, so maybe read through this thread to get an idea of what I'm running into: https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-flake8/issues/582

Comment: So after doing what malkir23 says, I get this error: Error running Flake8 Error: Failed to spawn command `flake8`. Make sure `flake8` is installed and on your PATH

and that's what I can't find my way around

Comment: I thought it would be as easy as typing 'which flake8' into the console and copy/pasting into the executable path in atom, maybe adjusting some of the file formatting. But that hasn't worked at all. I have no idea what else to do here I feel like I've tried everything within my, albeit limited, realm of knowledge.

Comment: I'm quite out of ideas myself, I develop in linux (ubuntu) since forever. Sorry :(

Comment: thanks for trying! I feel like there has to be someone out there who's experience the same issue. I'll try again tomorrow

Comment: there has to be a simple command or two to enter to terminal. Can I use cat or | ? I went to download rbox and hydrogen and have the same problem trying to access rScript. It's all downloaded, just not in the path. For anyone else who reads this, I'm using cmder/conEmu for terminal, not just cmd.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well, and just doing `pip install flake8` in cmd fixed it for me.